# Jitsi-Meet SDK - Get alert of push for incoming call React Native

Tags: push-notification, react-native, video-conferencing, jitsi-meet

I have implemented jitsi-meet video call successfully in my React Native app using [react-native-jitsi-meet SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jitsi-meet).

Both the user can join a call successfully with same URL. Now here, I want to get alert when user A start a call, user B should get alert to join that call. Right now I want to send alert to all users who has app installed, later I will manage to assign unique identifier, so only user for whom the call is generated can join that get alert to join.

Right now, I just want to get alert when call is initialized by first user. It can also be for specific user only so not all users can get notification. I don't know how exactly it works in jitsi.

My current implementation:

```
JitsiMeet.initialize();
    JitsiMeetEvents.addListener('CONFERENCE_LEFT', (data) => {
      console.log('CONFERENCE_LEFT');
    });
    JitsiMeetEvents.addListener('CONFERENCE_JOINED', (data) => {
      console.log('CONFERENCE_JOINED');
    });
    JitsiMeetEvents.addListener('CONFERENCE_WILL_JOIN', (data) => {
      console.log('CONFERENCE_WILL_JOIN');
    });
    setTimeout(() => {

      JitsiMeet.call("https://mydomain.name/" + finalName, this.state.isAudioEnable);

    }, 1000);
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: have you implemented push notifications for your app?

Comment: @bk7, Thanks for your time. I haven't implemented push notifications yet. I am expecting some alert from jitsi SDK.

Comment: @bk7, were you able to implement this push notification feature? I also need help in this regard